# How do I enable url rewriting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2, debian

I am using Debian Jessie. I want to enable URL rewriting. Many sites, such as [this blog](http://willjackson.org/blog/enable-clean-urls-drupal-debian-7-wheezy), suggest that I edit

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default
```

However, there is no such file, but it contains 000-default.conf, which contains the following code:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> 
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

There is no line that contains

```
AllowOverride None
```

Can I overwrite this file with the code given in the blog-post specified above?

After that, can I put a .htaccess file in my /var/www/html/somesite/ folder with the following code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^this/page/thispage this.php?page=thispage
```

to overwrite "this.php?page=thispage" with "this/page/thispage/"?

And (bonus question), is there a way to overwrite all GET requests, so that any link of the form "this.php?variable1=foo&variable2=bar" will result in a form "this/variable1/foo/variable2/bar"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">
    Allow from all
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

in your vhost

Your htaccess file needs to go in the document root, which is `/var/www/html`.

Then you can do:

```
Options -Multiviews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^this/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ this.php?$1=$2 [L]
RewriteRule  ^this/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ this.php?$1=$2&$3=$4 [L]
```

And that will make it so *when you enter this URL into the browser*: `http://example.com/this/a/b/c/d` and you'll see the page `/this.php?a=b&c=d` and the URL won't change.

Comment: Thanks, but one more question. What exactly is my vhost? Should I set up a new virtual host, or can I use the 000-default.conf. (Note that I have multiple projects on my document root)

Comment: @Yatoom "vhost" = "virtual host". It depends, the "default" is the virtual host that will get used if a request doesn't match a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` from any other vhost. If you plan on hosting a lot of sites, you may want to setup specific vhosts for each site, but if you only have 1 site, then using the default is fine.

Answer (score 1):

First you need enable rewrite mod on your machine:

`a2enmod rewrite`

if it's not isntalled, do that:

`apt-get install rewrite`

then edit your vhost zone with:

`Allow from all
AllowOverride All`

If you don't have your vhost file create yet, you can copy it from default:

`cd /etc/apache2/sites-available`

`cp 000-default yourwebsite.com`

After creating vhost file for a new website, enable it:

`a2ensite yourwebsite.com`

And last, you need to place `.htaccess` file in your document ROOT